# ognl.OgnlException: target is null for setProperty...?

Tags: java, struts2

I'm new to Struts 2. I'm creating a demo web application which allows a user to submit employee details on a jsp and show them on the next jsp. Following is the code:

**struts.xml**

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />

    <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

        <action name="empDetails" class="com.webapp.test.action.MyAction"
            method="employeeDetails">
            <result name="success">jsp/employeeDetails.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="addEmployee" class="com.webapp.test.action.MyAction"
            method="addEmployee">
            <result name="success">jsp/addEmployee.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**Action class**

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Employee emp = null; 

    public String addEmployee(){
        System.out.println("In addEmployee");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String employeeDetails(){
        System.out.println("In employeeDetails");
        System.out.println("Employee ID: "+emp.getEmployeeID());
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

In the above action class, Employee is a separate model class with the following attributes:

```
String employeeID;
String name;
String department;
```

Following is my JSP page to add an employee:

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Employee</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="empDetails">
<s:textfield name="emp.employeeID" label="Employee ID"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield name="emp.name" label="Name"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield name="emp.department" label="Department"></s:textfield>
<s:submit></s:submit>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

After filling in the employee details when I click on the Submit button, I get a nullpointer exception in the employeeDetails() method:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.webapp.test.action.MyAction.employeeDetails(MyAction.java:19)
```

and the server console displays the following exceptions:

```
ognl.OgnlException: target is null for setProperty(null, "department", [Ljava.lang.String;@acd4c9)
.....
ognl.OgnlException: target is null for setProperty(null, "employeeID", [Ljava.lang.String;@c5dd98)
....
ognl.OgnlException: target is null for setProperty(null, "name", [Ljava.lang.String;@5753b0)
```

Please explain what is the problem and how can I fill the employee model object from the JSP. I do not want to create getter setter methods in the Action class and also I do not want to use the ModelDriven interface.

Comment: Finally solved it .... the getter setter methods for Employee reference 'emp' in the MyAction class were missing ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The getter setter methods for the `Employee` object reference `emp` were missing in the `MyAction` class.

Problem resolved after creating the methods.

Thanks!!!