# Struts2: Updating the values of a "List Of Objects" inside a Map

Tags: java, collections, struts2, treemap, ognl

There is an object `ObjectA` which has a list of `ObjectB`. There is a `TreeMap` inside the `ObjectB`. This `TreeMap` has a `String` as key and a `List` of another object `ObjectC` as value. This `TreeMap` and the `list` inside has been displayed on the `jsp` using the `s:iterator` and `s:textfield` and it is being displayed correctly. i.e. the "values" inside the s:textfield are correct. Now, the problem arises when the textfield is modified. How do we capture the modified values inside ObjectC in the action class? With the code given here, the key ("Key1") comes in the action but the value is null.

**Java Code**

```
public class ObjectA implements Serializable {
private Integer attr1;
private List<ObjectB> objB;
//...getters and setters....
public class ObjectB implements Serializable {
private Integer attr11;
private TreeMap<String,List<ObjectC>> allPlainFields;
// ...getters and setters....
public class ObjectC implements Serializable {
private Integer attr111;
public String attr112;
// ...getters and setters....
```

**JSP Code**

```
<s:iterator value="objA.objB" var="currentObjB" status="currentGroupStatus">

  <s:iterator value="#currentObjB.allPlainFields" var="parentMap" status="headerStatus">
     <s:iterator value="#parentMap.value" var="fieldList" status="fieldStatus">

       <s:textfield  name="objA.objB[%{#currentGroupStatus.index}].allPlainFields['%{#parentMap.key}'][%{#fieldStatus.index}].attr112"/>


</s:iterator>                       

 </s:iterator>
```

**HTML rendered:**
    `<input type="text" id="review-act1_objA_objB_0__allPlainFields_'Key1'__6__attr112" value="Correct Value" name="objA.objB[0].allPlainFields['Key1'][0].attr112">`

**The object structure in the "VAriables" view of eclipse shows**:

```
objA    Object A  (id=955)  
objB    ArrayList<E>  (id=966)  
    elementData Object[10]  (id=967)    
        [0] ObjectB  (id=968)   
            allPlainFields  TreeMap<K,V>  (id=972)  
                comparator  null    
                descendingMap   null    
                entrySet    TreeMap$EntrySet  (id=979)  
                keySet  null    
                modCount    1   
                navigableKeySet null    
                root    TreeMap$Entry<K,V>  (id=980)    
                size    1   
                values  null    

        [1] ObjectB  (id=969)   
        [2] ObjectB  (id=970)   
        [3] ObjectB  (id=971)   
        [4] null    
        [5] null    
        [6] null    
        [7] null    
        [8] null    
        [9] null    
    modCount    4   
    size    4
```

****In the Eclipse "Variables" view, the value for allPlainFields is**:** {Key1=}

**EDIT(27-Feb-2013)**:

Tried this but didn't work. The values appear on jsp but when submitted, they don't come in action:

In `Action` class:

```
private TreeMap<String,ObjectCList> testTreeMap = new TreeMap<String,ObjectCList>();
//get,set and setting two keys in map "mykey1" and "mykey2"
```

In `ObjectCList` class:

```
private ArrayList<ObjectC> paramMdlList;
 //default constructor, get, set
```

In `JSP`:

```
<s:form id="test-map" method="post">
<s:iterator value="testTreeMap" var="pMap" status="hStatus">
     <li><label><s:property value="%{#pMap.key}" /></label> 
        <s:iterator value="%{#pMap.value.paramMdlList}" var="pList" status="innerStatus">
            <s:textfield name="testTreeMap['%{#pMap.key}'].paramMdlList[%{#innerStatus.index}].attr111"/>
            <s:textfield name="testTreeMap['%{#pMap.key}'].paramMdlList[%{#innerStatus.index}].attr112"/> 

        </s:iterator>


    </li>

</s:iterator>
<s:submit value=" " type='button' id="btnh1" action="saveTreeMap">
            <span>Save TreeMap</span>
</s:submit>
</s:form>
```

When the form is submitted, `updateTreeMap` method of the `action` is called. The map is printed as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map) :

```
public String updateTreeMap(){

    for (Map.Entry<String, ObjectCList> entry : testTreeMap.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
    }

    return SUCCESS;
```

}

What is "printed" :
    mykey1/ 
    mykey2/
i.e. **null values**

**The screen below shows values coming in jsp**
[image: screen showing values come in jsp]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struts2 binding a map inside an object to an action attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959003/struts2-binding-a-map-inside-an-object-to-an-action-attribute)

Comment: @Roman, The other link was for Map inside a list. This one is for List inside a Map inside a list. Logically, this should work in similar ways but surprisingly it's not.

Comment: Did you receive the answer from the first question? Everytime you change the structure we should duplicate the code of each other? Why to ask the same question several times. Earn rep via answering questions, then spend it on bounty.

Comment: @Roman, Yes I did receive the answer to the first question and I did accept it. Looks like one more level of a collection inside is not working. It looks like the same question but it isn't. Have you faced such a problem earlier?

Comment: I don't understand, as for me I never, never use such expressions, unnecessary complexity lead to bugs and months, years to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your latest update. If you are using `TreeMap` Struts2 cannot correctly determine type of elements inside it. Change declaration of `testTreeMap` from `TreeMap` to `Map`.

```
private Map<String,ObjectCList> testTreeMap = new TreeMap<String,ObjectCList>();
```

Or annotate `testTreeMap` with `com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.Element` annotation to tell Struts2 what type are elements inside map.

```
@Element(value = ObjectCList.class)
private TreeMap<String,ObjectCList> testTreeMap = new TreeMap<String,ObjectCList>();
```

Comment: It wouldn't have been possible to reach so close to the solution without the efforts of Andrea Ligios! Thank you Andrea!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would this element notation have worked for a `guava TreeBasedTable`? This is where this started and the earlier `TreeBasedTable` was replaced with map of lists. A `TreeBasedTable` hasn't exposed the default constructor and has a `.create` method instead. ex: `@Element(value = TreeBasedTable.class)
 Table<Integer,String,ObjectC> tableRepresentation = TreeBasedTable.create();`

Answer (score 5):

I've become curious and did other experiments.

I found out that neither `List`s inside `List`s, nor `Map`s inside `Map`s (and all the interpolations), declared as interface (`List`, `Map`), or as their implementations (`ArrayList`, `HashMap`, `TreeMap`) are correctly handled by the `XWork Converter`.

All the test cases have failed.

Maybe it's my fault, if so we really need some `OGNL` Experts here, because in the whole web there's nothing talking about this.

Then i tried what I was pretty sure that would have worked: encapsulating this informations in **custom objects**, in pure `OOP` way.

And it worked :)

Instead of

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> outerObjects;
```

you can use in your **Action**

```
private ArrayList<OuterObject> outerObjects; 

/* GETTERS AND SETTERS */
public ArrayList<OuterObject> getOuterObjects() {
    return outerObjects;
}
public void setOuterObjects(ArrayList<OuterObject> outerObjects) {
    this.outerObjects = outerObjects;
}
```

the **OuterObject** definition:

```
/* ELSEWHERE IN YOUR PROJECT... */
public class OuterObject{
    private ArrayList<InnerObject> innerObjects;

    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */
    public ArrayList<InnerObject> getInnerObjects() {
        return innerObjects;
    }
    public void setInnerObjects(ArrayList<InnerObject> innerObjects) {
        this.innerObjects = innerObjects;
    }       
}
```

the **InnerObject** definition:

```
public class InnerObject{
    String innerField;

    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */       
    public String getInnerField() {         
        return innerField;
    }
    public void setInnerField(String innerField) {
        this.innerField = innerField;
    }

}
```

the optional **execute()** method of your **Action** to test the preset values:

```
        InnerObject innerObj1 = new InnerObject();
        innerObj1.setInnerField("Inner Value 1");

        ArrayList<InnerObject> innerObjArrayList = new ArrayList<InnerObject>();
        innerObjArrayList.add(innerObj1);

        OuterObject outerObj1 = new OuterObject();      
        outerObj1.setInnerObjects(innerObjArrayList);

        outerObjects = new ArrayList<OuterObject>();
        outerObjects.add(outerObj1);
```

the **JSP**:

```
    <s:form>
        <s:textfield name="outerObjects[0].innerObjects[0].innerField" />
        <s:submit/>
    </s:form>
```

(when iterating, simply use `[%{#stat.index}]` for `List`s and `['%{#stat.index}']` for `Map`s)

The same solution is applicable for every kind of iterable structure (probably except the `Guava` stuff that needs the `.create()` method to be invoked).

Of course this is not handy in every case, in your example you have already a huge structure <s>and this will almost double it</s>, but it works, it's OOP, your OGNL will be clearer (because of names) and however seems to be the only way.

Note: the Classes must be real stand-alone Classes, not `Inner Classes`, another case where `OGNL` fails to autowire the objects.

Hope that helps

---

**EDIT**

What you need then, is only one more level:

change this:

```
private TreeMap<String,List<ObjectC>> allPlainFields;
```

to this

```
private TreeMap<String,ObjectX> allPlainFields;
```

and create an `ObjectX` containing a private field that is a `List<ObjectC>`.

It will work.

Comment: Will try it out. However, When I changed the `s:textfield` to    `<s:textfield  name="objA.objA[%{#currentGroupStatus.index}].allPlainFields.get('%{#parentMap.key}').get(%{#fieldStatus.index}).attr112"/>` , I got an error in the logs which said: _Unexpected Exception caught setting 'objA.objB[0].allPlainFields.get('Key1').get(0).attr112' on 'class com.vm.action.Act1: Error setting expression 'objA.objB[0].allPlainFields.get('Key1').get(0).attr112' with value ['testval', ]_. Please notice an addition "," and a space next to testval. This is the closest I've got till now;OGNL tried something :)

Comment: Vicky, I've got closer many times (for example there are differences between List<List<String>> and ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>; appearently, in the first case OGNL has problems trying to "guess" the correct implementation for the interface... btw, thinking about it, your structure won't "almost double", you just need only ONE more level. I'm updating the answer right now with it.

Comment: @Andrea, I had already added one extra layer based on your first response and I think, it shouldn't matter(?) Here are the 2 different errors I got with 2 different mappings at the Map level:
**Scenario1**: Unexpected Exception caught setting `'rqPGPrmMdl.rqGrp[1].pFWrap.allPFields['DefaultHeader'].paramMdlList[7].pValue'` on 'class `com.hm.action.Act1`: Error setting expression `'rqPGPrmMdl.rqGrp[1].pFWrap.allPFields['DefaultHeader'].paramMdlList[7].pValue' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@3b9b2222'`
`ognl.NoSuchPropertyException: java.lang.String.paramMdlList`

Comment: **Scenario2**: Unexpected Exception caught setting `'rqPGPrmMdl.rqGrp[1].pFWrap.allPFields.get('DefaultHeader').paramMdlList[5].pValue'` on 'class `com.hm.action.Act1`: Error setting expression `'rqPGPrmMdl.rqGrp[1].pFWrap.allPFields.get('DefaultHeader').paramMdlList[5].pValue'` with value `'[Ljava.lang.String;@3c67312'`

`ognl.OgnlException: source is null for getProperty(null, "paramMdlList")`

Comment: Check carefully *every* `getter` and `setter`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064366/ognl-ognlexception-target-is-null-for-setproperty

Comment: checked every getter and setter ..no issues some it gets the key in the action "Default Header" but no values...

Comment: @AndreaLigios Updated the question with further findings. Had to take a break from this to finish something else.

Comment: @AndreaLigios : The final one step given by Aleksandr M worked. However, it wouldn't have been possible to reach so close to the solution without your efforts! Thanks a ton!Is there anything on SO to appreciate the great efforts you have taken?