# How to submit a composite object using form in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have the following classes

```
public class Address {
  private String unit;
  private String street;
  ... getter and setters go here....
}

public class Person {
   private String name;
   private Address address;
   public Person(){
      address = new Address();
   }
   ... getter and setters go here...
 }

public class Employee extends Person {
    ... 
}
```

For example I can access the unit filed of address class using the following code

```
 <s:form method="POST" action="updateEmployee">
    <s:textfield name ="unit" label="Unit" value="%{employee.address.unit}" />
    <s:textfield name ="name" label="Name" value="%{employee.name}" />
 </s:form>
```

but when I submit the form it sends all the fields except the fields of address class. It shows the unit is null.

```
 @Action
 public class myaction implements ModelDriven {

 Employee emp = new Employee();

 public String updateEmployee(){
    System.out.println("Unit is" + employee.getAddress().getUnit();
    System.out.println("Unit is" + employee.getName();
    return "SUCCESS";
 }

 public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}

public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}

@Override
public Object getModel() {
    return employee;
}
```

Comment: can u show the actual form - what HTML elements / struts tag u r using ?

Comment: put <s:debug /> and check whats happening

Comment: @user1428716, question is updated

Comment: why would label be part of your Value Stack when you submit it ?

Comment: because it shows the value of each field and allows users to change the values and submit the form to update the values on backend.

Comment: @user1428716 is right, you must specify the path in the `name` attribute. You can do a lot more complex things with that, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006868/struts2-updating-the-values-of-a-list-of-objects-inside-a-map
 P.S: your employee variable is missing... :D

Comment: @AndreaLigios what do you mean by path would you give me an example ?

Comment: the linked one is not good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<s:textfield name ="employee.address.unit" label="Unit" value="%{employee.address.unit}" />
<s:textfield name ="employee.name" label="Name" value="%{employee.name}" />
```