# Updating the values of a custom object inside a Map say Object A which contains a list of Object B

Tags: java, struts2

I followed the below link: My issue is also similar but not able to troubleshoot it. 
[Struts2: Updating the values of a "List Of Objects" inside a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006868/struts2-updating-the-values-of-a-list-of-objects-inside-a-map?rq=1)

I have a map of `Integer` and `ObjA`, a custom object which consists of only `List<ObjB>`.

```
private Map<Integer, ObjA> displayMap = new HashMap<Integer, ObjA>();
```

`ObjB` contain parameters like size, status etc.

**JAVA code**  I am populating the `displayMap` with all the object values and displaying it on the jsp. But when I submit the form again then the `displayMap` becomes null.

```
public String displayColumn() throws Exception {

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDoors.length; i++) {
             int k = 1;
            List<ObjB> objBList = new ArrayList<ObjB>();
            while (k <= numberOfDoors[i]) {
                ObjB objB =new ObjB();
                objB.setSizeCd("1");
                objBList.add(objB);

                doorNoCounter = doorNoCounter + 1;
                k++;
            }

            ObjA objA = new ObjA();
            objA.setObjBList(objBList);
            displayMap.put(i+1, objA);
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}


   private class ObjA{


private List<ObjB> objBList;

public List<ObjB> getObjBList() {
    return objBList;
}

public void setObjBList(List<ObjB> objBList) {
    this.objBList= objBList;
}
```

}

```
private class objB{
     protected String sizeCd;

        public String getSizeCd() {
        return sizeCd;
    }
    public void setSizeCd(String sizeCd) {
        this.sizeCd = sizeCd;
    }

}
```

**JSP Code snippet:**

```
    <table class="tableStyle">

     <tr>   

        <s:iterator status="outerStat" value="displayMap" var="parentMap">

        <tr>
                            <s:iterator status="innerStat" value="%{#parentMap.value.objBList}" var="listLocker">
            <td class="labelStaticText">Select Size Code:</td>

            <td > 
             <s:textfield name="displayMap['%{#parentMap.key}'].objBList[%{#innerStat.index}].sizeCd" value="%{sizeCd}"/>               
                        </td>
        </s:iterator>
        </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </tr>
```

Comment: did you populate a jsp?

Comment: Please, show us 1) your struts.xml (or annotation mapping if using convention plugin), 2) the destination action 3) the full jsp form including the submit button. +1 btw, nice question showing efforts. Oh, and be sure ObjB has a default constructor.

Comment: The action methods are getting called fine. Also the data is dispalyed on the UI fine. The only issue is when I submit the form I do not get the value in the Map, hence not attaching the struts xml mapping.. The map is giving null value. I edited the code and added it again. Please let me know if anything else I need to add.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your values are displayed correctly means nothing, because even if a `value` attribute is right, the `name` attribute will be used to send the item and they're unrelated.

BTW now (after your edit) it's clear what the problem is: you are using two private inner classes.

Please, use a public class for both `ObjA` and `ObjB`, and it will work.

EDIT:

> The only issue is when I submit the form I do not get the value in the Map, hence not attaching the struts xml mapping..

Since you are not attaching struts mapping, I can't see if your interceptor stack is nicely configured for this action. Then do it yourself, ensure you have the Default Interceptor Stack, or at least that the `ParametersInterceptor` is there. Remember that if you add an interceptor of your own, you need to add a stack too, otherwise you will be using a single Interceptor instead of adding it to the others.

Comment: I modified the inner class to public, but still the same problem persists.