# Looping through a list of lists using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a list of courses depending on school code. This list of courses is added to another list, making it a list-of-lists.

**Action Class:**

```
private List<String> schoolList;
private List<String> socList;
private List<String> sobList;
private List<String> sodList;
private List<String> genlist;
private List<List<String>> courseList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

@Override
public String execute() {
    FacultyManager fm = new FacultyManager();
    schoolList = fm.getColumn("school_description", "school");

    genlist = fm.getCoursesBySchoolCode("GEN");
    sobList = fm.getCoursesBySchoolCode("SOB");
    socList = fm.getCoursesBySchoolCode("SOC");
    sodList = fm.getCoursesBySchoolCode("SOD");     

    courseList.add(genlist);
    courseList.add(sobList);
    courseList.add(socList);        
    courseList.add(sodList);        

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

**JSP:**

```
<c:forEach var="school" items="${schoolList}" varStatus="ctr">
    <ul>
        <li>${school}
            <ul>
                <c:forEach var="course" items="${courseList}">
                    <li>${course}</li>
                </c:forEach>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</c:forEach>
```

**Output**
[image]

How do I make it so the output is:

- GENERAL EDUCATION

  - DEPARTMENT OF GENERAL EDUCATION
- SCHOOL OF BUSINESS

  - BSBA - FINANCIAL MANAGEMENT
  - BSBA - MARKETING AND ADVERTISING

... and so on.

Comment: Or just [use objects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15009137/1654265).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating *the whole list of courses in all schools* over and over again, thus repeating the same output as if you called `courseList.toString()` method multiple times.

You should instead iterate over *a concrete list of courses in a current school*, which most likely (but nowhere stated in your question) depends on the current iteration index of the outer `<c:forEach>` loop. This is in turn captured in the `index` property of the exported `ctr` variable (that is zero-based) of the school list iteration index.

Thus, you should iterate over a specific list of the `courseList` list, depending on the current school. You can do this by calling `courseList.get(ctr.index)`, assuming you are on EL2.2+.

This all yields:

```
<c:forEach var="school" items="${schoolList}" varStatus="ctr">
    <ul>
        <li>${school}
            <ul>
                <c:forEach var="course" items="${courseList.get(ctr.index)}">
                    <li>${course}</li>
                </c:forEach>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</c:forEach>
```

That said, `List<List<String>>` does not sound as a good model choice. For instance, if you change insertion order you'll get the wrong courses in your view. `Map<String, List<String>>` construct fits better your domain model as it can be used to map school name to a list of course names unambiguously.

Another option to consider seriously is the usage of objects (you are doing OOP in the end). You should turn away from plain strings and move into objects domain. To start, investigate the following class hierarchy:

```
public class Course {
    //...
    private School school;
    //...
}

public class School {
    //...
    private List<Course> courses;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `courseList.get(ctr.index)` worked. I was wondering how to get the value of `ctr` from `varStatus`. Accepted.

Comment: Agree with the OOP recommendation

Comment: `courseList.get(ctr.index)` appropriately answers the question at hand. In the event I try the OOP approach, I will post another thread. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to iterate the list inside the list , you can achive it by

```
<c:forEach var="school" items="${schoolList}" varStatus="ctr">
    <ul>
        <li>${school}
            <ul>
                <c:forEach var="course" items="${school}">
                    <li>${course}</li>
                </c:forEach>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</c:forEach>
```

You need to iterate the `inner` list from the list you pass it to the jsp.

**Update**

In the case if you are using `Map<String, List<String>>` , you can iterate it as

```
 <c:forEach var="school" items="${schoolList}" varStatus="ctr">
        <ul>
            <li>${school.key}
                <ul>
                    <c:forEach var="course" items="${school.value}">
                        <li>${course}</li>
                    </c:forEach>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </c:forEach>
```

You can use the `key` and `value` to get the values from the `Map`

Comment: I replaced my code with your snippet and this is what happend - [click](http://s18.postimg.org/c92ozi3jd/output2.png).

Comment: way of populating the list in server side seems to be little clumpsy, above is the syntax to iterate the `list of lists` . i advise you to use `Map<String,List<String>>` for your case

Comment: Hi, I have not used a `Map` before, could you kindly post how the Action Class would look like?

Comment: @SanKrish I was not the one who downvoted and I don't intend to do that, but I'll explain the downvote. Your initial answer didn't take into account that most possibly `school` is in fact a `String` and not a `List` thus *this part should be wrong*. And your update doesn't answer the initial question but instead proposes a brand new solution so *it answers a different question*.