# Populating Action class instance variables from URL in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

Facing an issue with passing values from my html form to action class. Created a sample project to test the functionality and have the same issue here. I have the following classes:

### TestBean

```
package com.struts2test.beans;

public class TestBean {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

### TestBeanHolder

```
package com.struts2test.beans;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestBeanHolder {
    private Map<Integer, TestBean> testBeanMap;
    private List<TestBean> testBeanList;
    private Map<Integer, List<TestBean>> testBeanListMap;

    public Map<Integer, TestBean> getTestBeanMap() {
        return testBeanMap;
    }
    public void setTestBeanMap(Map<Integer, TestBean> testBeanMap) {
        this.testBeanMap = testBeanMap;
    }
    public Map<Integer, List<TestBean>> getTestBeanListMap() {
        return testBeanListMap;
    }
    public void setTestBeanListMap(Map<Integer, List<TestBean>> testBeanListMap) {
        this.testBeanListMap = testBeanListMap;
    }
    public List<TestBean> getTestBeanList() {
        return testBeanList;
    }
    public void setTestBeanList(List<TestBean> testBeanList) {
        this.testBeanList = testBeanList;
    }
}
```

### TestAction

```
package com.struts2test.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.struts2test.beans.TestBeanHolder;

public class TestAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private TestBeanHolder testBeanHolder;

    public TestBeanHolder getTestBeanHolder() {
        return testBeanHolder;
    }

    public void setTestBeanHolder(TestBeanHolder testBeanHolder) {
        this.testBeanHolder = testBeanHolder;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

When my url is `http://localhost:8080/Struts2Test/test?testBeanHolder.testBeanMap[0].value=1`, `testBeanHolder.testBeanMap` of my action gets populated with key of `0` mapping to a `TestBean` instance with `value=1`.

When the url is `http://localhost:8080/Struts2Test/test?testBeanHolder.testBeanList[0].value=1`, `testBeanHolder.testBeanList` gets populated with single instance of `TestBean` with `value=1`.

I am try to populate `testBeanListMap` property of `testBeanHolder` and doesn't work. The `testBeanListMap` is created but empty. Here is the URL I am trying `http://localhost:8080/Struts2Test/test?testBeanHolder.testBeanListMap[0][0].value=1`

Comment: The problem is in new object instance creation. Use some simpler structure.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15009137/1654265

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url `http://localhost:8080/Struts2Test/test?testBeanHolder.testBeanListMap[0][0].value=1` won't work because you are using wrong parameter name. Thus `testBeanHolder.testBeanListMap[0][0].value` is a name of the parameter that maps to the object which has a property of complex type (collection of collections). Struts2 can't handle such scenarios, . But you can wrap a second collection with an object and use a collection of objects. The name would change to `testBeanHolder.testBeanListMap[0].object[0].value`.

Comment: Thanks @Roman. It worked. Needed a holder for `List<TestBean>`

Comment: @JamesJithin have you read [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15009137/1654265) linked in my comment ? Roman, why saying *not sure if struts can handle such scenarios* if we know since that Q&A that it can't ?

Comment: He's asking you a question directly related to your answer; opening a new question to reply to your answer would be inappropriate.

Comment: ... he asked why you said it. I don't see what the issue is. The purpose of asking a question is to get an answer--not just to answer it yourself, no? Not having an answer seems like the *perfect* time to ask a question.

Comment: *I* wasn't asking why.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code which worked, adding modified classes:

### TestBeanListHolder

```
package com.struts2test.beans;

import java.util.List;

public class TestBeanListHolder {
    private List<TestBean> testBeans;

    public List<TestBean> getTestBeans() {
        return testBeans;
    }

    public void setTestBeans(List<TestBean> testBeans) {
        this.testBeans = testBeans;
    }

}
```

### TestBeanHolder

```
package com.struts2test.beans;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestBeanHolder {
    private Map<Integer, TestBean> testBeanMap;
    private List<TestBean> testBeanList;
    private Map<Integer, TestBeanListHolder> testBeanListMap;

    public Map<Integer, TestBean> getTestBeanMap() {
        return testBeanMap;
    }

    public void setTestBeanMap(Map<Integer, TestBean> testBeanMap) {
        this.testBeanMap = testBeanMap;
    }

    public Map<Integer, TestBeanListHolder> getTestBeanListMap() {
        return testBeanListMap;
    }

    public void setTestBeanListMap(
            Map<Integer, TestBeanListHolder> testBeanListMap) {
        this.testBeanListMap = testBeanListMap;
    }

    public List<TestBean> getTestBeanList() {
        return testBeanList;
    }

    public void setTestBeanList(List<TestBean> testBeanList) {
        this.testBeanList = testBeanList;
    }
}
```

### URL

`http://localhost:8080/Struts2Test/test?testBeanHolder.testBeanListMap[1].testBeans[0].value=somevalue`

Comment: A *perfect* compliment to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32987629/573032)

Answer (score -1):

The expression `testBeanHolder.testBeanListMap[0][0].value` is not a valid OGNL expression.

See [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html) for a complete reference of what is allowed.

Comment: `testBeanHolder.testBeanListMap[0][0].value` is a valid expression.

Comment: What's not valid about it?