# arraylist of arrarylist of custom objects in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, struts2, ognl

I hava to access a ArrayList of ArrayList of Custom objects on the jsp page from the struts2 action page:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<ProjectMemberDTO>> projectMember = new ArrayList<>();
```

I know how to access the ArrayList of Objects but I'm not able to deal with the above situation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I am simply saying that I have

Comment: ArrayList<ArrayList<ProjectMemberDTO>> projectMember=new ArrayList<>()

Comment: in my struts action page.Now i want to access this list on the jsp page.

Comment: for the simple arraylist of object i can use this                                <s:iterator  var="i" step="1" value="projectMember">

Comment: but for above arraylist this will not print the exact data

Comment: Printing should be fine, but with submitting there could be some problems with populating parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<s:iterator value="projectMember" var="currentMember">
    <br>-Occurrence of the outer ArrayList
    <s:iterator value="#currentMember">
        <br>----Occurrence of the inner ArrayList; my object value: 
        <s:property value="myObject.myAttribute" />
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

But you should consider migrating to a more structured object, because this seems unnecessarily noisy.

Also consider that

- a list should be called `projectMembers`, since they're more,
- for the declaration should be used the interface `List`, not the implementation `ArrayList`
- while you can iterate in the page any kind of structure, [a List of Lists can't be sent back to the action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15009137/1654265). Then, again, consider restructuring it a bit.