# JSP Populate back HashMap<String, ArrayList<CustomObject>> with Struts 2

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, hashmap

I'm having some difficulties to populate back my map (`HashMap<String, ArrayList<CustomObject>>`) from my jsp.

I can access the map in my jsp and iterate on it to get the different values, but as soon as I submit this values I don't retrieve it as a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<CustomObject>>` like it should be, but as a `HashMap<String, string representation of the list object>`.

Here is a code sample of the jsp :

```
<s:iterator value="daysOfWeek" var="jour" status="stat">
    <s:iterator value="%{plageRecords[#stat.index]}" var="plage" status="innerStat">
        <s:select name="plageRecords[%{#stat.index+']['+#innerStat.index}].heureDebut" 
                  list="startHourList"/>
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: How the `plageRecords` looks like in your action? Maybe relevant [Struts2: Updating the values of a “List Of Objects” inside a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15006868/1700321)

Comment: plagreRecords was an HashMap<String, ArrayList<PlageRecord>> with a few elements that I was ab le to display in the jsp. I changed it to HashMap<String, PlageRecordList> accordingly to the link you gave me, but I'm still not getting anything in my action after submit

Comment: It should be `plageRecords['map_key']['list_index']`. This is very strange `+']['+`. :)

Comment: Yes I already changed it. I agrea it was a really wierd way to proceed, I just did this way because my code editor was giving me errors otherwise